# How to Mock a test with two mutually exclusive parameters in Pester

Tags: powershell, pester

I am writing a helper function to login to Azure. I can call `Connect-AzAccount` with either `-SubscriptionId` or `-SubscriptionName` but not both.

How do I Mock this? I have tried...

```
Mock Connect-AzAccount { return @{Name = 'Fake Name'} } -ParameterFilter { $SubscriptionId } -Verifiable
Assert-LoginAzureAz -SubscriptionName '0123'
```

I have tried...

```
Mock Connect-AzAccount { return @{Name = 'Fake Name'} } -ParameterFilter { '0123' -eq $SubscriptionId } -Verifiable
Assert-LoginAzureAz -SubscriptionName '0123'
```

I have tried...

```
Mock Connect-AzAccount { return @{Name = 'Fake Name'} } -ParameterFilter { $null -eq $SubscriptionId } -Verifiable
Assert-LoginAzureAz -SubscriptionName '0123'
```

But all of these pass. Do I need to create two Mocks? How do I assert the negative one didn't get called?  Can I use `Assert-MockCalled` with two different Mocks?

EDIT:
Adding other tests I've tried...

```
Mock Connect-AzAccount { throw 'Called Connect-AzAccount by SubscriptionName' } -ParameterFilter { $SubscriptionName }
Mock Connect-AzAccount { return @{Name = 'Fake Name'} } -ParameterFilter { $SubscriptionId } -Verifiable

Assert-LoginAzureAz -SubscriptionName '0123'
```

Still passes.

Comment: Maybe if you specify two [parameter sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7#parametersetname-argument) in your function definition, then you can ensure that only the one you want is called during a test since PowerShell would prevent an invalid combination being used.

Comment: Can you have only one parameter required in a ParameterSet? Let's see what happens...

Comment: Nope. Everything still passes.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
Mock Connect-AzAccount { if([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($SubscriptionId)) {throw 'Called Connect-AzAccount by SubscriptionName'} else {return @{Name = 'Fake Name'}} } -ParameterFilter { $null -ne $SubscriptionId } -Verifiable

Assert-LoginAzureAz -SubscriptionId '0123'  ### Passes
Assert-LoginAzureAz -SubscriptionName '0123'  ### Fails
```

Resetting Mocks is not a good idea (I'm not even sure it's supported). And because it's a parameter PS starts them with a value of String.Empty (yes, even if you set the default to `[string] $SubscriptionId = [NullString]::Value`).

So we have to test for IsNullOrWhitespace in the Mock and throw an error.